# Sending input data from android to php

Tags: php, android

These codes are executed after a button is pressed. I'm trying to send the strings data to the php file in my server. But the application has stopped after i pressed the button. Can i know whats the problem here? Any helps are really appreciated :D

```
        HttpClient client = new DefaultHttpClient();
        HttpPost hpost = new HttpPost("http://myservername.com/postTest.php");
        status = mStatus.getText().toString();
        event = mEvent.getText().toString();
        time = mTime.getText().toString();
        try{
            List<NameValuePair> nameValuePairs = new ArrayList<NameValuePair>();
            nameValuePairs.add(new BasicNameValuePair("status", status));
            nameValuePairs.add(new BasicNameValuePair("event", event));
            nameValuePairs.add(new BasicNameValuePair("time", time));
            hpost.setEntity(new UrlEncodedFormEntity(nameValuePairs));
            client.execute(hpost);
            mStatus.setText("");
            mEvent.setText("");
            mTime.setText("");
        }catch (UnsupportedEncodingException e){
            Toast.makeText(this, "Unsupported Encoding Exception " + e.getMessage(), Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        }catch (ClientProtocolException e){
            Toast.makeText(this, "Client Protocol Exception " + e.getMessage(), Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        }catch (IOException e){
            Toast.makeText(this, "IO Exception "+e.getMessage(), Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        }
```

Comment: Look at [NetworkOnMainThread Exception](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6343166/android-os-networkonmainthreadexception)

Comment: Could you include the stacktrace from logcat?

Comment: Did you used AsuncTask.Class for POSTING data on server? You shouldn't run network OP in MainActivity.

Answer (score 2):

put your code to thread

```
new Thread(new Runnable() {

    @Override
    public void run() {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        // do something
    }
}).start();
```

and check your AndroidManifest.xml permission

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET"/>
```

Answer (score 0):

Probably problems is:

1. You Trying to send data from UI Thread. It can be resolved by using Thread class:

   new Thread(){
       @Override
       public void run(){
           // your sending code herre
       }
   }.start();
2. If you using another thread you can't show Toast in your Thread. It can be resolved using runOnUIThread(Runnable) method of Activity

   }catch (UnsupportedEncodingException e){
      runOnUITehread(new Runnable(){
          @Override
          public void run(){
              Toast.makeText(this, "Unsupported Encoding Exception " + e.getMessage(), Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
          }
      });
   }

   Or using [Handler](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/Handler.html)
3. You have an NullPointerException